# Clang ast changing filename

Tags: windows, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I am traversing the clang AST on Windows 7 platform.  I notice that when a file name contains a character such as ╥, clang changes the pi character to ΓòÑ 
What is the reason for this, and to go further, how can I determine what characters will be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The windows Console uses 437 as the encoding, instead of UTF-8.  Changing the output encoding to UTF-8, for the process, resolved all problems